# Check if same Object already exists in Dictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

I have following issue:
In my Dictionary there are several complex objects with different keys. I do not want multiple identical objects in my dictionary. I tried methods like

```
if (dict.Equals(myObj))
{
   // do not add it into the dictionary
}
else
{
   // add it into the dictionary
}
```

But this does not work. It goes always into the else section. How can I compare the dictionary-items with my objects?

Comment: you compare dictionary and myObj

Comment: what's the point of having a dictionary, with keys and values if you check the uniqueness by the value instead of the key? Maybe use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) instead

Comment: So, show the actual declaration of the dictionary. Also are you trying to compare the value or the Key. Note that when comparing objects you are doing a reference check unless you have implemented the appropriate interfaces. Also note that this `if (dict.Equals(myObj))` is actually comparing the reference of your object to the dictionary, which is not what you want.

Comment: In short, you need to add a [MCVE] and more clarity to this question.

Comment: Did you really say you were gonna loop through a dictionary? That's like the worst possible solution you could do.

Comment: You stored the object in a dictionary and object has three properties. So what is the key-value pair of the dictionary? Could you provide a simple demo which you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You can override the default methods Equals() and GetHashCode() of your object.

Answer (score 3):

The question is really whether two 'identical' objects added to the dictionary will be identified when using a comparison method such as the LINQ suggestion higher up. If they are not, you may need to use something along the lines of the [IComparable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-5.0).

Comment: If you could show an example and how the OP would use this code, this would be the best answer

Comment: @TheGeneral `IComparable` is for sorting. The OP's question is one of equality. Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, and probably also implementing `IEquatable<T>` would be more appropriate. Alternatively, creating a type that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` and passing that to the dictionary if not wanting to modify the type directly. That said, I agree with `derpirscher` in that the dictionary may not even be the right collection type.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`ContainsValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containsvalue) method:

```
if (!dict.ContainsValue(myObj)) {
    dict.Add(myKey, myObj);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same result as my method..
It adds every Object into the dictionary. In the Object is an other Object - the value of the second Object is different. Do I need to compare the Object of the Object maybe?

Comment: @Kathrin I don't understand that sentence. Care to clarify?

Comment: Sure. For example: 
Object from Dictionary has following items int numer, string name, Material materialObject
The Object I want to compare with that one in the dictionary has the same items but the value of materialObject is different. I do not know if that is the reason of the problem.

Comment: @Kathrin  Could you please add some example data to your question and describe the desired output there? And if you say, that a property of your object is different, it's obviously not an identical object, is it? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Maybe Dictionary is not the best Collection for your purpose

Comment: @Mureinik Don't you need to provide equality comparison for this to work? **myObj**s with same values but different instances are not the same **myObj**s.